# Which pythonIDE i can use to link with VPS django project

Tags: python, django, ide

I have Django running in my VPS .
I find it very hard to ssh everytime and edit files and commands there.

I know there are IDEs available like komodo , Pycharm but i want to use that IDE which link with my remote VPS .

I don't know if thats exactly possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoud be able to do what you are asking for using the [Remote System Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?nav=/50) in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) (<strike>it is provided by default, it's not external addon</strike>. [Not true](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g1installing.html)). For Python development in Eclipse also consider using the [PyDev plugin](http://pydev.org).

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: hi , Do i need install Perl and do all stuff mentioned here http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g1installing.html , its looking very complex

Comment: @bidu You have two choices. 1. follow the installation guide I gave the url and do the install as they say (don't care Perl). I did that way (very easy) and it worked for me without Perl. 2. Download an Eclipse distribution having RSE integrated out of the box, for example the [IDE for Java EE Developers edition](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2). I suggest you to try, RSE works pretty fine. Ask if you have problems.

Comment: Actually i have JEE eclipse installed. i found the RSE when i go to new , with options like linux ftp, etc but then i keep going next , next and finish. Then i don't know what to do , where that link will appear , how to enter username , password. i was expecting to see something in project explorer but i see no new folder there

Comment: You have to access your files expanding the sFtp files tree. See my edited answer.

Comment: i got it , i had go to window and then plcae the RSE to the editor in order to see that

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend doing all your development locally (on localhost).  Once you have a working product upload to your VPS.

Django has [tools for this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs) built right into it.